# When should I not implement a trait for references to implementors of that trait?

Tags: reference, rust, traits

If I have a trait, and a function that accepts a generic type constrained to that type, everything works fine. If I try to pass in a reference to that type, I get a compilation error.

```
trait Trait {
    fn hello(&self) -> u32;
}

struct Struct(u32);

impl Trait for Struct {
    fn hello(&self) -> u32 {
        self.0
    }
}

fn runner<T: Trait>(t: T) {
    println!("{}", t.hello())
}

fn main() {
    let s = Struct(42);

    // Works
    runner(s);

    // Doesn't work
    runner(&s);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&Struct: Trait` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:24:5
   |
24 |     runner(&s);
   |     ^^^^^^ the trait `Trait` is not implemented for `&Struct`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <Struct as Trait>
note: required by `runner`
  --> src/main.rs:13:1
   |
13 | fn runner<T: Trait>(t: T) {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I can fix the issue by implementing the trait for any reference to a type that implements the trait:

```
impl<'a, T> Trait for &'a T
where
    T: Trait,
{
    fn hello(&self) -> u32 {
        (*self).hello()
    }
}
```

The piece of information that I'm missing is when **shouldn't** I implement this? Asked another way, why doesn't the compiler automatically implement this for me? Since it currently doesn't, I assume there must be cases where having this implementation would be disadvantageous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The particular trait you are writing here only takes `self` by reference, and that is the only reason it is possible to write the additional implementation you did.

For this reason, taking the parameter to `runner()` by value is probably undesirable; you should instead be taking it by reference. This guideline can apply generally: if it is possible to implement the trait for a reference then rather than wondering “should I implement it?” you should wonder “why *would* I implement it?” for the only cases where you would use it should probably be altered to take the object by reference in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

> when shouldn't I implement this? Asked another way, why doesn't the compiler automatically implement this for me? Since it currently doesn't, I assume there must be cases where having this implementation would be disadvantageous.

As an example, the [`Default`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/index.html) trait immediately came to mind.

```
pub trait Default {
    fn default() -> Self;
}
```

I could implement it for `T`, but there is no way to automatically implement it for `&T`.