# Why do you need to implement Add for adding two variables with the trait Num?

Tags: generics, rust

I have a function called `add_vec`. It takes two vectors and creates a new one, by performing an elementwise add on the pair of elements from the zipped vectors.

```
extern crate num;
use num::traits::Num;

fn add_vec<N: Num>(v1s: Vec<N>, v2s: Vec<N>) -> Vec<N> {
    let mut v3s = Vec::new();
    for (v1, v2) in v1s.iter().zip(v2s.iter()) {
        v3s.push(v1 + v2)
    }
    v3s
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::add_vec;
    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let v1s = vec![1, 0, 3];
        let v2s = vec![0, 1, 1];
        let v3s = add_vec(v1s, v2s);
        assert_eq!(v3s, vec![1, 1, 4]);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I end up with the following error message:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `&N`
  --> src/lib.rs:14:18
   |
14 |         v3s.push(v1 + v2)
   |                  ^^
   |
note: an implementation of `std::ops::Add` might be missing for `&N`
  --> src/lib.rs:14:18
   |
14 |         v3s.push(v1 + v2)
   |                  ^^
```

I know this is answered in [Requiring implementation of Mul in generic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184358/requiring-implementation-of-mul-in-generic-function) but I do not understand why I need to implement the `Add` trait. As if there are numbers that cannot be added...

Is there a way to solve this without implementing `Add`? I want to create a version of `add_vec` that uses `-`, `%`, `*`, `/` instead of `+`, and implementing the respective traits for each operation sounds like a drudge. I'm only interested in signed integers and floats, so perhaps there exists a trait for these subtypes of num?

My `Cargo.toml` for convenience:

```
[package]
name = "minimal_example_2"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["User"]

[dependencies]
num = "0.1.36"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The important thing to realize is that the code isn't attempting to add two `N`s; the code is attempting to add two *references to `N`* (`&N`). Look at the error message (emphasis added):

> binary operation `+` cannot be applied **to type `&N`**

By using `iter`, you are iterating on *references* to values inside the vector. There's no guarantee that a trait is implemented for a reference to a type that implements the trait.

- [When should I not implement a trait for references to implementors of that trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28799372/155423)
- [How do I implement the Add trait for a reference to a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28005134/155423)

In addition, `T: Add<T, Output=T>` does **not** imply `&T: Add<&T, Output=T>`.

> but I do not understand why I need to implement the `Add` trait. As if there are numbers that cannot be added...

Why do you assume that `N` **is a number**? *Any possible type* that exists in Rust is welcome to implement any trait, and that includes `Num`. If it made sense, you could implement `Num` for your own type.

> perhaps there exists a trait for these subtypes of num?

Again, once a trait exists, **any type** is welcome to implement it.

---

For what it's worth, I'd implement it like this:

```
use std::ops::Add;

fn add_vec<'a, N>(v1s: &'a [N], v2s: &'a [N]) -> Vec<N>
    where &'a N: Add<Output = N>
{
    v1s.iter().zip(v2s.iter()).map(|(v1, v2)| v1 + v2).collect()
}
```

See [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String) or Vec (&Vec) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423) (also we just don't *need* to take ownership here). Using `map` is going to be more efficient - it can preallocate the output vector all at once.

However, if you really wanted to consume the vectors:

```
fn add_vec<N: Num>(v1s: Vec<N>, v2s: Vec<N>) -> Vec<N> {
    v1s.into_iter()
        .zip(v2s.into_iter())
        .map(|(v1, v2)| v1 + v2)
        .collect()
}
```

Note that `into_iter` consumes the vectors, yielding values and not references. Thus the `Num` trait can be applied.

Comment: But according to http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/trait.Num.html, `Num: ...+  Add<Self> + ...`, which you might think means you can assume `Add`.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson yes, you can add together two values of a type that implements `Num` (and thus `Add`), but *not* two references to values of a type that implement `Num`. `T: Add<T, Output=T>` does not imply `&T: Add<&T, Output=T>`.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. What is the `'a` and the `Output` in the signature called? Want to read up on them further.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat [a lifetime](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/lifetimes.html) and [an associated type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/associated-types.html), respectively. I'd **highly** recommend reading the [**entire** book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/); it has the collected answers to many questions that people ask when starting Rust.