# When do you take input as T or &T in a Rust generic function?

Tags: generics, rust

My class notes have code that implements the `HasArea` trait and prints the area, similar to the Rust Book example. The professor's note is as following:

```
trait HasArea<T> {
    fn area(& self) -> T,
}

fn print<T: Display, S: HasArea<T>>(s: &S) {
    println!("", s.area());  // println sth must impl Display trait
}

struct Circle {
    x: T,
    y: T,
    r: T,
}

impl <T: Copy + Mul <Output = T>>
    HasArea<T> for Circle<T>  
{
    fn area(&self) -> T {
        self.r * self.r
    }
}
```

Comparing that to the Rust Book, which uses `shape: T` as input:

```
trait HasArea {
    fn area(&self) -> f64;
}

struct Circle {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    radius: f64,
}

impl HasArea for Circle {
    fn area(&self) -> f64 {
        std::f64::consts::PI * (self.radius * self.radius)
    }
}

fn print_area<T: HasArea>(shape: T) {
    println!("This shape has an area of {}", shape.area());
}

fn main() {
    let c = Circle {
        x: 0.0f64,
        y: 0.0f64,
        radius: 1.0f64,
    };

    print_area(c);
}
```

I am not sure why the professor uses `s: &S`, while the Rust Book uses `shape: T`. Can anyone help compare when implementing a generic function, when do we pass a input as `x: &T` and when `x: T`?

Comment: Unrelated, but I'm interested: what university? I will delete this comment after you answered ;-)

Comment: Not a problem, UC-Davis undergraduate CS class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anyone help compare when implementing a generic function, when do we pass a input as `x: &T` and when `x: T`?

It's the same as when you would accept `x: Foo` and `x: &Foo`. Taking a `x: Foo` gives the function the ownership of of `x`, and (unless `x` is `Copy`) the caller will not be able to use it again.

In the Rust Book example, `print_area` takes the ownership of `circle`, so you cannot use `circle` after the `print_area(circle);` line. For example, the following:

```
fn main() {
    // ...
    print_area(c);
    print_area(c);
}
```

throws this error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `c`
  --> <anon>:29:16
   |
28 |     print_area(c);
   |                - value moved here
29 |     print_area(c);
   |                ^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `c` has type `Circle`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

In my experience, most of the time you'll want to take `: &T` (like your Professor's note). Only when you need the ownership of the struct would you need to use `: T`. The Rust Book probably uses `: T` for simplicity.

Comment: I disagree with *most of the time you'll want to take `&T`*. If a trait is [implemented for all references to items of that type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28799372/155423), then there's no reason to add *more* indirection.

Comment: @Shepmaster good point (I wanted to mention it along with `Copy` but forgot). But then again I haven't seen a lot of impls for `&T` compared to `T`. What do you think about the Rust Book's example consuming `T` just to print its area?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question of generics but a question of borrowing and ownership. If you want your input to be moved into function then you use `T`, otherwise if you just want to borrow it you use `&T` or `&mut T`.

[Relevant book section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ownership.html)