# How to unbox elements contained in polymorphic vectors?

Tags: vector, rust, boxing

After reading [this answer to "Vector of objects belonging to a trait"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25819164/129805), it looks like Rust does automatic unboxing.  Is this the case?

My code doesn't compile and I don't understand how that answer's code could compile.

What is the correct way to unbox the elements of a polymorphic vector, one containing boxed traits?

I've read [Rust by Example](http://rustbyexample.com/std/box.html) and [the `Box` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html) and I can't see any method that looks like `unbox()`.

My code is:

```
trait HasArea {
    fn area(&self) -> f64;
}

struct Circle {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    radius: f64,
}

impl HasArea for Circle {
    fn area(&self) -> f64 {
        std::f64::consts::PI * (self.radius * self.radius)
    }
}

struct Square {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    side: f64,
}

impl HasArea for Square {
    fn area(&self) -> f64 {
        self.side * self.side
    }
}

fn print_area<T: HasArea>(shape: T) {
    println!("This shape has an area of {}", shape.area());
}

fn main() {
    let c = Circle {
        x: 0.0f64,
        y: 0.0f64,
        radius: 1.0f64,
    };

    let s = Square {
        x: 0.0f64,
        y: 0.0f64,
        side: 1.0f64,
    };

    print_area(c);
    print_area(s);

    let vec: Vec<Box<HasArea>> = Vec::new();
    vec.push(Box::new(c));
    vec.push(Box::new(s));

    for x in vec {
        print_area(x)
    }
}
```

My error is:

```
   Compiling rustgraph v0.1.0 (file:///home/chris/lunch/rustgraph)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Box<HasArea>: HasArea` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:54:9
   |
54 |         print_area(x)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `HasArea` is not implemented for `Box<HasArea>`
   |
   = note: required by `print_area`
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can dereference it like `print_area(*x)`, but it won't work for other reasons: the `Sized` bound for the `print_area` argument. Your function needs to know the size of its arguments.

You have other problems in your code: you are trying to push into an immutable vector and you are trying to box moved values. These were moved after you used it in `print_area()`.

My opinion is that it would be easier to make `print_area` a method which takes an immutable reference. This will work as you expected.

```
trait HasArea {
    fn area(&self) -> f64;
    fn print_area(&self) {
        println!("This shape has area of {}", self.area());
    }
}

struct Circle {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    radius: f64,
}

impl HasArea for Circle {
    fn area(&self) -> f64 {
        std::f64::consts::PI * (self.radius * self.radius)
    }
}

struct Square {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    side: f64,
}

impl HasArea for Square {
    fn area(&self) -> f64 {
        self.side * self.side
    }
}

fn print_area<T: HasArea>(shape: &T) {
    println!("This shape has an area of {}", shape.area());
}

fn main() {
    let c = Circle {
        x: 0.0f64,
        y: 0.0f64,
        radius: 1.0f64,
    };

    let s = Square {
        x: 0.0f64,
        y: 0.0f64,
        side: 1.0f64,
    };

    c.print_area();
    s.print_area();

    let mut vec: Vec<Box<HasArea>> = Vec::new();
    vec.push(Box::new(c));
    vec.push(Box::new(s));

    for x in vec {
        x.print_area();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but how does the `x: Box<HasAreas>` in `x.print_area();` get unboxed?  Is the unboxing automatic and where can I read the rules?

Comment: It's just automatic dereferencing for method call, that's why rust doesn't have both `obj.method()` and `pointer->method()` syntaxes, you can read here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/deref-coercions.html

Answer (score 5):

To answer your *direct* question:

> How to unbox elements contained in polymorphic vectors?

You **cannot**. Once something has been boxed and had the concrete type erased, that's it. A `Box<SomeTrait>` cannot be made back into a `SomeConcreteType`, because nothing knows what that concrete type is.

---

To solve the problem in the code... check the error message again:

> the trait bound `Box<HasArea>: HasArea` is not satisfied

That's because a reference to a trait (or a box of a trait) [**does not implement that trait**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28799372/155423)!

To allow your program to compile and run as you originally wrote it, you only need to implement the trait for boxes, and we might as well do references too:

```
impl<T: ?Sized> HasArea for Box<T>
    where T: HasArea
{
    fn area(&self) -> f64 { (**self).area() }    
}

impl<'a, T: ?Sized> HasArea for &'a T
    where T: HasArea
{
    fn area(&self) -> f64 { (**self).area() }    
}
```

This allows your fixed-up main to run:

```
fn main() {
    let c = Circle {
        x: 0.0f64,
        y: 0.0f64,
        radius: 1.0f64,
    };

    let s = Square {
        x: 0.0f64,
        y: 0.0f64,
        side: 1.0f64,
    };

    print_area(&c);
    print_area(&s);

    let vec: Vec<Box<HasArea>> = vec![Box::new(c), Box::new(s)];

    for x in vec {
        print_area(x)
    }
}
```

Here, we pass a reference of `c` and `s` to `print_area`, to avoid transferring ownership. We also use the `vec!` macro to construct the vector with much less ceremony.

Answer (score 4):

> After reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/25819164/129805 it looks like Rust does automatic unboxing. Is this the case?

Not as automatic as you might think. In fact, you were looking for an `unbox` method while `Box<T>` implements `Deref` for target `T`. That means you should either call `as_ref()` or rely on `Deref` coercion. Note that a `T` is not possible for unsized types, and since you are relying on polymorphic types, the consumer function will have to accept a reference.

I took the liberty of fixing `main` and `print_area` to make it work. The vector was also improperly declared as immutable.

```
fn print_area<T: HasArea + ?Sized>(shape: &T) {
    println!("This shape has an area of {}", shape.area());
}

fn main() {
    let c = Circle {
        x: 0.0f64,
        y: 0.0f64,
        radius: 1.0f64,
    };

    let s = Square {
        x: 0.0f64,
        y: 0.0f64,
        side: 1.0f64,
    };

    print_area(&c);
    print_area(&s);

    let mut vec: Vec<Box<HasArea>> = Vec::new();
    vec.push(Box::new(c));
    vec.push(Box::new(s));

    for x in vec {
        print_area(&*x)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to what E_net4 suggested, instead of boxing your traits you could use a `Vec` with references to make it work:

```
fn print_area<T: HasArea+?Sized>(shape: &T) {
    println!("This shape has an area of {}", shape.area());
}

let mut vec: Vec<&HasArea> = Vec::new();
vec.push(&c);
vec.push(&s);

for x in vec {
    print_area(x)
}
```

Comment: My understanding of the question is that OP really wanted to have an owning vector.

Comment: Yes, I'm just including an alternative way to handle a `Vec` of traits since there other issues with the OP's code and they might want to do additional research.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is also useful, but what I really didn't understand was the Rust *was* doing automatic unboxing in the referenced question.  As you might guess, I'm just learning Rust.