# How can I create a generic function that takes any signed or unsigned integer and converts it to a u8?

Tags: generics, rust, borrow-checker

I came up with a function that is supposed to take any signed or unsigned integer and map it to a `u8`. Every negative value becomes 0 while every value above 255 should be 255. I know this is trivial, my goal is only to get an understanding on how generics work.

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn as_byte<T>(source: T) -> u8
where
    T: TryInto<u8>,
    T: PartialOrd<u8>,
{
    if source < 0 {
        return 0;
    }
    if source > 255 {
        return 255;
    }

    source.try_into().unwrap_or(0)
}
```

I thought it would make sense to constrain my generic to whatever I actually want to do with `source`, so I declared that I want to be able to compare it to an `u8` and be able to do a conversion to `u8` (which *should* not fail if I catch a value out of range before).

If I call `as_byte(1234i32)`, it will fail since there is no implementation of `PartialOrd<u8>` for `i32`. Even if there were an implementation, this will fail due to `source` being moved on the first comparison and then being used after move in the second check.

If I pass `source` by reference like `as_byte(&1234i32)` it gets even worse. Now the `TryInto<u8>` trait is not implemented either, since there is no `From<&i32>` for `u8`.

I understand why these issues are raised, but I can not figure out how to resolve them. I tried to change the constraints to `where &'a T` or changed the parameter to `source: &T`, or both. That left me with similar issues where traits for reference types were not implemented. This leaves me feeling like I didn't understand the concept of the borrowing/references correctly in the first place.

Where is the error in my thought process?

1. If `PartialOrd<u8> for i32` existed, what should this method's declaration look like?
2. Knowing that `PartialOrd<u8> for i32` does not exist, how else should I constrain the type parameter? [Why do I get the error "the trait `Foo` is not implemented for `&mut T`" even though T implements the trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928882/why-do-i-get-the-error-the-trait-foo-is-not-implemented-for-mut-t-even-th) is related and somewhat answers my question - but I can (and probably should) not implement traits for primitive/std types, can I?

Comment: checkout the `num` crate/project

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I looked through the source code and I don't understand how this should be helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write `as_byte()` like this:

```
fn as_byte<T>(source: T) -> u8
where
    T: TryInto<u8> + From<u8> + PartialOrd,
{
    if source < 0.into() {
        return 0;
    }
    if source > 255.into() {
        return 255;
    }

    source.try_into().unwrap_or_else(|_| unreachable!())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c293ea57cee7039afca7073150c9ef38)

Since `u8` is very small, it makes more sense to convert 0 and 255 to `T` and then compare than the other way around. Requiring `PartialOrd<u8>` makes `as_bytes` compile in isolation, but not when invoked with a concrete integer type. This is because Rust's integer types currently don't implement comparison to types of different width, you need to convert both operands to the same type.

I'm not sure why you had problems with `source` getting moved - [`PartialOrd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html) defines comparison on `&self` and `&rhs`, so it should never cause a move.

Comment: My bad. The move came from me trying to call `.into()` on source in one of my attempts. I didn't consider that I can just call `.into()` on the integer literal, thank you!

Comment: @Link64 If you run into issues with moves in other generic code that works with numbers, you can simply require `T: Copy` (implemented for all primitive numbers) or even `T: Clone` (implemented for both primitive numbers and bignums, resolves to `Copy` for primitives). For `T: Copy` `source.into()` would simply not move `source`, and for `T: Clone` you'd use `source.clone().into()`.

Comment: Not working for i8 type, just play with `assert!(as_byte(10i8) == 10);`