# Is there a way to avoid dereferencing with trait objects?

Tags: function, parameters, rust, traits, dereference

I came across a problem which I thought would be perfect to use trait objects for. While I managed to make it work, it looks far more complicated than it should so I would like to know if there is a more optimal way to use trait objects.

Exemplified code:

```
/* This takes a slice of objects implementing trait and compares each of 
 them with all other objects in the slice, if they interact with each other
 both objects should call a certain function with the other object as a parameter.

 This is used for a collision system, in case you know of a better way to solve this please
 let me know. */

fn foo(objects: &mut [Box<Trait>]) {
    let mut active_objects: Vec<&mut Box<Trait>> = vec!();

    for current in objects.iter_mut() {
        for other in active_objects.iter_mut() {
            if (**current).is_interacting(&***other) {
                current.boo(&mut ***other);
                other.boo(&mut **current);
            }
        }

        active_objects.push(current);
    }
}

trait Trait {
    fn boo(&mut self, other: &mut Trait);

    fn is_interacting(&self, other: & Trait) -> bool;
}
```

Is there a way I don't have to write something like `&***` every time I want to use the actual object?

`if (**current).is_interacting(&***other)` becomes `if current.is_interacting(&***other)` as Rust automatically dereferences in this case.

Comment: You do not need to dereference `current`, it is automatic.

Comment: @Boiethios Thanks :), this takes me from 10 `*` to 8.

Comment: That's a beginning. There is a problem on `other` because the type is `&mut &mut std::boxed::Box<Trait>`.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But I did not find a way to prevent this, as `active_objects` has to be a vector of references, as I would move out of borrowed context otherwise, and I have to `iter_mut` to be able to mutate the traitobject, so while I agree that `&mut &mut` is something undesirable I don't know how to do it otherwise...

Comment: You could ask the question: "How to visit all pair mutably in a vector?". I would search in this direction: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.1.0/collections/slice/struct.Permutations.html or https://crates.io/crates/permutohedron/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove **all** dereferences in your code:

```
fn foo(objects: &mut [Box<Trait>]) {
    let mut active_objects: Vec<&mut Box<Trait>> = vec![];

    for current in objects.iter_mut() {
        for other in active_objects.iter_mut() {
            if current.is_interacting(other) {
                current.boo(other);
                other.boo(current);
            }
        }

        active_objects.push(current);
    }
}
```

You enable this by [implementing the trait itself for references and boxes to the type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28799372/155423):

```
impl<'a, T> Trait for &'a mut T
where
    T: Trait + ?Sized,
{
    fn boo(&mut self, other: &mut Trait) {
        (**self).boo(other)
    }

    fn is_interacting(&self, other: &Trait) -> bool {
        (**self).is_interacting(other)
    }
}

impl<T> Trait for Box<T>
where
    T: Trait + ?Sized,
{
    fn boo(&mut self, other: &mut Trait) {
        (**self).boo(other)
    }

    fn is_interacting(&self, other: &Trait) -> bool {
        (**self).is_interacting(other)
    }
}
```

This is a one-time piece of code that you add near your trait definition allowing the call site to be cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was possible to use `impl` on `&`.

Answer (score 3):

As [red75prime points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159914/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-dereferencing-with-traitobjects#comment77290950_45161147), `as_mut()` is a possibility to take a mutable reference to a `Box`, which provides an even better solution:

```
fn foo(objects: &mut [Box<Trait>]) {
    let mut active_objects: Vec<&mut Box<Trait>> = vec!();

    for current in objects.iter_mut() {
        for other in active_objects.iter_mut() {
            let current = current.as_mut();
            let other = other.as_mut();

            if current.is_interacting(other) {
                current.boo(other);
                other.boo(current);
            }
        }

        active_objects.push(current);
    }
}

trait Trait {
    fn boo(&mut self, other: &mut Trait);

    fn is_interacting(&self, other: &Trait) -> bool;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but I am convinced there is a simpler solution to do what OP wants.

Comment: Well, I agree ;) This is just one step further

Comment: `let current = current.as_mut(); ...` works too. And I'm not sure it can be simpler.

Comment: It definitely looks better than my first test, I did some testing and it is actually faster than my original function by about 4% which I most certainly did not expect. In case there won't be a better answer I will accept yours. Thanks!

Comment: `as_mut`  and `borrow_mut` don't seem to effect process speed at all, so using `as_mut` should be cleaner due to the fact that I don't have to `use` anything.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to keep references to `Box` objects in the `active_objects` vector.  This should work and eliminates most of the dereferencing:

```rust
fn foo(objects: &mut [Box<Trait>]) {
    let mut active_objects: Vec<&mut Trait> = vec!();

    for current in objects.iter_mut() {
        let current = current.as_mut();
        for other in active_objects.iter_mut() {
            if current.is_interacting(*other) {
                current.boo(*other);
                other.boo(current);
            }
        }

        active_objects.push(current);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, but it's worth to remember that `&mut Trait` is a fat pointer that takes twice as much space as `&mut Box<Trait>`.

Comment: But that means that it uses less indirections so it could provide faster access

Comment: I compared the speed of both answers, this one is 10 to 15% faster than the other functions, which is impressive, the best solution yet! Thanks

Comment: @ViktorChvátal, right, but as always it's better to bench. Decreased number of memory accesses could be offset by increased cache pressure.