# Type matching a BTreeSet inside a tuple in Rust

Tags: rust

I have the code as follows (part of a larger library). The compiler is telling me that a tuple does not implement a trait, but I have both an implementation for a tuple and for the one element of that tuple. And it works with another type of tuple.

Why does the tuple `(BTreeSet<Annotation>)` not get matched here?

```
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

pub struct Axiom {}
pub struct Annotation {}

pub struct AnnotatedAxiom {
    pub axiom: Axiom,
    pub annotation: BTreeSet<Annotation>,
}

trait Render {
    /// Render a entity to Write
    fn render(&self);
}

impl<'a, T: Render> Render for &'a BTreeSet<T> {
    fn render(&self) {}
}

impl<'a, A: Render> Render for (&'a A,) {
    fn render(&self) {
        (&self.0).render();
    }
}

/// The types in `Render` are too long to type.
macro_rules! render {
    ($type:ty, $self:ident,
     $body:tt) => {

        impl Render for $type {
            fn render(& $self)
                $body
        }
    }
}

render!{
    Annotation, self,
    {
    }
}
render!{
    Axiom, self,
    {
    }
}

render!{
    AnnotatedAxiom, self,
    {
        // Axiom implements Render
        (&self.axiom).render();

        // Annotation implements Render
        (&self.annotation).render();

        // A 1-element tuple of Axiom implements Render
        (&self.axiom,).render();

        // A 1-element tuple of Annotation does!?
        (&self.annotation,).render();

    }
}

fn main() {}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=17fe19749ec41a799984df21be33ecf7&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

```
error[E0599]: no method named `render` found for type `(&std::collections::BTreeSet<Annotation>,)` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:62:29
   |
62 |         (&self.annotation,).render();
   |                             ^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `render` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `(&std::collections::BTreeSet<Annotation>,) : Render`
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `render`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `Render`
```

Comment: Are the macros **required** to reproduce this problem? Is `Axiom` required to reproduce the problem? Please review how to create a [MCVE], emphasis on **minimal**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a gap in the implementation chain:

```
impl<'a, T: Render> Render for &'a BTreeSet<T> {
    // ....
}

impl<'a, A: Render> Render for (&'a A,) {
    // ...
}
```

The first `impl` provides `Render` for a *reference* to a `BTreeSet`, whereas the second one provides an implementation for a tuple of a *reference to something that implements* `Render`. Since `BTreeSet` itself does not implement `Render` (only a reference to it does!), the compiler will refuse to work.

This is a situation where it's more ergonomic to abstract away from references, since `Render` appears to be fitting for any reference to another `Render`able value. Implement this trait for all references `&T` where `T: Render`:

```
impl<'a, T> Render for &'a T
where
    T: Render,
{
    fn render(&self) {
        (**self).render();
    }
}
```

The remaining implementations become slightly simpler as a consequence of this:

```
impl<T> Render for BTreeSet<T>
where
    T: Render,
{
    fn render(&self) {}
}

impl<A> Render for (A,)
where
    A: Render,
{
    fn render(&self) {
        (&self.0).render();
    }
}
```

[Working Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f35dc5387d4816def1e8826b41e0a7e7&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

See also:

- [When should I not implement a trait for references to implementors of that trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28799372/1233251)

Comment: As a second question, how did you work this out? I struggled hard with this, but couldn't find a way to get the compiler to tell me why the tuple wasn't a subclass of the thing I expected.

Comment: @PhilLord Just observation with a sufficiently experienced eye. Note that the compiler was already telling you the missing constraint: `(&std::collections::BTreeSet<Annotation>,) : Render` was unsatisfied, which would either mean that the trait was not implemented for `(&T,)` or that `BTreeSet` was not implementing it.

Comment: Yeah, guessed it was experience. Problem with the compiler is I knew what it was missing, but I couldn't see why, given there was a `impl` for `&BTreeSet`. Anyway, thanks for the help. A bit more learned about rust.